# Super simple CSS method in jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, css

I'm pretty well-versed in CSS but am new to using jQuery, and I'm just working on implementing it in some things I'm currently working on. I thought I was solid on the basics of jQuery, but the effects I was trying to apply were not working. So, I did what I usually do when I'm debugging and stripped down to the bare basics and took out any variables, etc. Still no response.

This is a very simple line of js and I'm completely baffled why it isn't applying. I know it's probably something very obvious, but I've gone through it carefully, and if I can get this basic thing to work I can obviously do more with it. Here's a fiddle with my simple, stripped down code. In this I'm just trying to get jQuery to add a border-radius style to the outline I added of the hero. http://jsfiddle.net/5rbmjauq/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#hero").css("border-radius", "10px");
});
```

Thanks for your help and sorry for the newbie question.

Comment: You forget to connect jQuery in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5rbmjauq/1/

Comment: Also in your "real-life" environment, you should load the jQuery javascript file before your first reference to any jQuery api. Obviously, but nevertheless.